# No data was written in output source : rxDataStepXdf function

Tags: r, bigdata, revolution-r

I have executed below code for selecting rows & column from a .xdf file & creating a new .xdf file but its not working. Below is the code & message shown after execution:

```
S_date <- as.Date("2014-05-01")   

rxDataStepXdf(inFile = "/poc/revor/data/ext_merchant_account.xdf",
              outFile = "/poc/revor/data/ext_merchant_account_filtered.xdf",
              rowSelection = ((CUR_MER_STA_CD %in% c("A","R")) & 
                              (CLNT_MAN_CHAN_CD %in% c("I","X"," ")) & 
                              (MER_SETUP_DT < S_date)), 
              varsToKeep = c("SE_NO","SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD"),
              transformObjects = list(S_date = S_date),
              overwrite = TRUE)
```

Message :

```
WARNING: No data was written to the output data source.
```

Below is the .Xdf file structure :

```
File name: /poc/revor/data/ext_merchant_account.xdf
Number of observations: 13529673
Number of variables: 74
Number of blocks: 136
Compression type: zlib
```

Just want to filter rows & column based on some criteria but the output .xdf file is not getting created.

Enviorment in which I am running the code:

```
Revolution R enviornment on Hadoop cluster.
```

Could anyone point out the mistake that I am doing over here.

Thanks for your help in Advance....:)

Cheers,

Amit

Comment: Are you sure that given the constraints you passed to ``rowSelection`` that there are actually any rows returned?

Comment: @DerekMcCraeNorton : yes , when executing same data in R it does return a dataframe. PFB the code used in R:

a <-  ext_merchant_account[(ext_merchant_account$CUR_MER_STA_CD %in% c("A","R")) & (ext_merchant_account$CLNT_MAN_CHAN_CD %in% c("I","X"," ")) & (ext_merchant_account$MER_SETUP_DT < S_date),c("SE_NO","SEIMS_INDUS_DS_CD")]